# checking for equality between an int and float in C

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, int, equality

I came across this piece of code :

```
int x=3;
float y=3.0;
if(x==y)
  printf("x and y are equal");
else
  printf("x and y are not equal");
```

Why does this code print "x and y are equal"?? 
Here if y=3.1(say), then the code prints "x and y are not equal".
Someone please explain how is this happening.

Comment: when the values are equal, the expression `x==y` produces `true`, and the `if`-`else` executed the first `printf` statement. when the values are not equal, this does not happen.

Comment: Are you asking why an `int` value of `3` is equal to a `float` value of `3.0` ? (and just fyi, comparing floating-point with *anything* for *equality* is a [**terrible idea**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)).

Comment: Also see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143032/about-comparing-an-integer-and-a-float-double-in-c-c?rq=1)

Comment: My question is basically directed towards the behaviour of '==' operator. I can predict it from the result of my code but I want a clear understanding of the same.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Comparing floating-point numbers for equality is a fine enough idea if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @tmyklebu does this look like a question that would be asked by someone that meets your qualification?

Comment: @WhozCraig: No.  However, filling people's heads with superstitions is a good way to make sure people *don't* figure out what's going on.

Comment: @tmyklebu I concur. I provided one of several links to the subject discussed on this forum in detail. Hopefully it is investigated (was somewhat the point of providing it in the first place).

Comment: @WhozCraig: The link you posted is irrelevant.  Note that 3 is exactly representable as a `float` and that no arithmetic is taking place here.  All your comment does is reinforce the unfortunately widely-held superstition that floating-point numbers are not to be trusted.

Comment: Note that because each of 32-bit int and 32-bit float contain values that do not exit in the other type, telling whether a 32-bit int and a 32-bit float represent the same value can be tricky. See for instance http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=535 and https://twitter.com/spun_off/status/467929922259144704

Comment: @tmyklebu If that was what you read from that so be it. I never claimed, nor intended to claim, that floating point numbers are cannot be "trusted". Had that been my intention, I would have said so. I referred specifically to *equality* comparison. That the OP's number of choice happened to be one that can withstand exact representation doesn't change that fact *at all*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is relational comparison between int and float directly possible in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161199/is-relational-comparison-between-int-and-float-directly-possible-in-c)

Answer (score 16):

Comparisons between arithmetic types are subject to the so-called *usual arithmetic conversions* (§5/9, §5.9/2, §5.10/1). Emphasis mine.

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield
>   result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result.
>   This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions, which are defined as follows:
>
> — If either operand is of scoped enumeration type (7.2), no conversions are performed; if the other
>   operand does not have the same type, the expression is ill-formed.
>
> — If either operand is of type `long double`, the other shall be converted to `long double`.
>
> — Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, the other shall be converted to `double`.
>
> — **Otherwise, if either operand is `float`, the other shall be converted to `float`.**
>
> — Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands. Then the following
>   rules shall be applied to the promoted operands:
>
> > — If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is needed.
> >
> > — Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types, the
> >     operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank shall be converted to the type of the
> >     operand with greater rank.
> >
> > — Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the
> >     rank of the type of the other operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to
> >     the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.
> >
> > — Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of
> >     the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type shall
> >     be converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
> >
> > — Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the
> >     type of the operand with signed integer type.

Answer (score 5):

When you try to compare an int with a float, the int gets converted to float first.

So `3 == 3.0f` actually tests `float(3) == 3.0f`, which is true.

On the other hand, `3 == 3.1f` tests `float(3) == 3.1f`, which is false.

Comment: "which is true" ... because sufficiently small integer values are represented exactly.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I rarely use numbers bigger than 16,777,216 ;)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes, an IEEE754 float has 24 bits of precision.

Answer (score -2):

In this question x is an integer value whereas y is a float value... an integer value and a float value cannot be equated...so inorder to check equality we have to typecast either float to integer or vice versa... Hope this may help to clear your concept