# How does the relational "is equal to" operator work

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=3;
    float y=3.0;
    if(x==y)
        printf("\n x and y are equal");
    else
        printf("\n x and y are not equal")

    return 0;
}
```

The code prints "x and y are equal".
Please explain how did this happen.

Comment: What did you expect to happen, and why?

Comment: Did you read https://floating-point-gui.de/ ? Did you refer to [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) ? Did you read the  [C11 standard](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) ? Did you read  [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) ?

Comment: It is best described in the [C standard - 6.5.9 Equality operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9) . Really, any (full) answer will be just a bunch of citations from there

Comment: The working are **as if** both `x` and `y` values are converted to `double`. The converted values are compared (perhaps bit-by-bit) and are found to be equal because `3.0f` converted to `double` has the same representation as `3` converted to `double`

Comment: your `int` will be type-converted to `float` (EDIT or `double`, I'm not 100% sure) automatically so that the left hand side and right hand side of the operator matches in type and then 3.0f and 3.0f will be compared and found to be equal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [checking for equality between an int and float in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067499/checking-for-equality-between-an-int-and-float-in-c)

Comment: It's called "Implicit Type Conversion."  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-c/

Comment: If you are trying to recreate an example about "broken floating point math", the value of choice is typically `0.3`, not `3.0`.

Answer (score 5):

When comparing an int variable to a float variable using `==`, the int is converted to a float implicitly first, and then the comparison is made.

Hence, `float(x) == y` means `3.0f == 3.0f`, which is true, that's why you it executes:

```
printf("\n x and y are equal");
```

Comment: Although it is correct that the `int` is converted to `float`, "float is larger than int" is not really the right way to describe the reason for that.  Interpreted as a statement about the size in bytes of the two types, it is downright false for many C implementations.  Rather, this is covered by the "usual arithmetic conversions", which specify it for the case in question directly, not as an application of a general rule based on any variation on size.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the catch, the comment on size variation was added as an edit by another user to my original answer.