# Why isn't my method generating the expected outputs?

Tags: c

I'm currently doing an assignment where I've been handed a complete program that determines whether a point is inside a rectangle or not. The main method gathers data from the user, and calls the method "inside" to do the necessary calculations.

My task was to rewrite the main method to instead provide a series of test cases to the "inside" method. The main method then records what test cases yielded incorrect results, and prints them out for the user to read.

Here is the "inside" method.

```
int inside(double x, double y, double x1, double y1, double x2, double, y2)
{
    int x_inside;
    int y_inside;

    if (x1 < x2)
        x_inside = x > x1 && x < x2;
    else
        x_inside = x > x2 && x < x1;
    if (y1 < y2)
        y_inside = y > y1 && y < y2;
    else
        y_inside = y > y2 && y < y1;
    return x_inside && y_inside;
}
```

And here is part of the main method. It consists of several blocks like this one, containing test cases.

```
result = inside(1.00001, 1.00001, 1, 1, 2, 2);
char input1[119] = ("1.00001, 1.00001, 1, 1, 2, 2 \n");
if (result == 1); {
    printf("%s %s", errormessage, input1);
    totalErrors++; }
```

The problem is that the program tells me that all of the test cases yielded incorrect results, no matter what values I give the variables in the "inside" method. I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something really simple here, but I just can't figure it out. By the way, I know that the test cases displayed on here are all out of whack, but that's not the thing. I tried changing the `if (result == 1)` part to `if (result == 0)`, but the result was still that I had 5 errors.

If something is unclear, please ask.

Comment: The `inside()` *function* (C does not have "methods") returns 1 if the point described by the first two arguments is in the interior of the rectangle described by the other four, and returns 0 otherwise.  It therefore appears that you do have the wrong criterion in the excerpt of your `main()` function that you presented.  I cannot speak to any code or test cases that you have not presented.

Comment: If you write tests, you want to check if the result is what it should be. So the `if (result == 1)` or `if (result == 0) ` should depend on the test data you're using

Comment: Can you give a runnable code please ? I tried your function and it return 1 when it is inside and 0 when it's not inside. So basically your function is working. However, I think the code you wrote here isn't the one you are testing because there is many errors like the ';' after the if, the ',' in the parameter of your function.

Comment: Duplicating `1.00001, 1.00001, 1, 1, 2, 2`, once as arguments to `inside` and once for the `input1` array is certainly not what you should do.

Comment: Given that you are reporting unexpected test behavior when you use `result == 0` *and* `result == 1`, it would help if you posted several of the test cases you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misplaced `;` Look carefully.

```
  if (result == 1); {
    printf("%s %s", errormessage, input1);
    totalErrors++; }
```

Same as

```
  if (result == 1); // why the ;?  Code has no effect

  // always print and increment error count
  printf("%s %s", errormessage, input1);
  totalErrors++;
```

OP likely wanted

```
result = inside(1.00001, 1.00001, 1, 1, 2, 2);
int expected = tbd_code();
char input1[119] = ("1.00001, 1.00001, 1, 1, 2, 2");

// No ; after the )
if (result != expected) {
    printf("%s test:%s result:d expected:d\n", errormessage, input1, result, expected);
    totalErrors++; 
}
```

Comment: Well there we go. Just as simple as I expected it to be. Thank you so much for taking your time to answer this!

Answer (score 0):

1: fix the comma placement in your arguments for inside.
Aside from that I tested your function itself, and it does work. 
2: fix the semi colon inside your if statement. That is also a problem, as it will also run your error. 3: If your goal is to print an error when you're inside your square, keep it. Otherwise result == 0 should be in its place.

```
if (true) /* runs this */;
{
    // and this
    printf("%s %s", errormessage, input1);
    totalErrors++; 
}

if (false) /* doesn't run this */;
{
    // but always runs this.
    printf("%s %s", errormessage, input1);
    totalErrors++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `inside` method returns 1 when (x,y) is inside the rectangle described by (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), and 0 when it is not. Your code considers a return value of 1 to be a failure.
2. As presented, your `inside` method won't compile. Fix the comma after the 'double'.
3. You may have issues with real test cases because you are comparing ints against doubles. Not sure what your intended behavior is, but see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22143606/2591870) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
struct TestCase
{
  double x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2;  // values of test case
  int expected;                 // expected outcome of test
} TestCases[] =
{
  // list of test cases
  {1.00001, 1.00001, 1, 1, 2, 2,  1},
  {1.00001, 100,     1, 1, 2, 2,  0}
};

int main()
{
  int errors = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(TestCases) / sizeof(TestCases[0]); i++)
  {
    struct TestCase t = TestCases[i];

    printf("Test %d (%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf) ", i, t.x, t.y, t.x1, t.y1, t.x2, t.y2);

    if (inside(t.x, t.y, t.x1, t.y1, t.x2, t.y2) == t.expected)
      printf("passed\n");
    else
    {
      errors++;
      printf("failed\n");
    }
  }

  printf("%d errors encountered\n", errors);
}
```

Now you can write your test cases in one single place, and you can add as many test cases as wanted without adding any additional code.

Consider also points 2 and 3 of Jamie Davis answer.

Comment: This is actually a completely valid solution to the whole assignment (I won't plagiarize it though, don't worry). The only thing I don't understand about your solution is where int expected gets its value from. How would I specify what each test case is supposed to yield?